# Unity 5.3.1, I have deleted a splash image but it still exist somewhere and appears in beginning

Tags: xcode, splash-screen, unity-game-engine

I don't know if its a bug in unity 5.3.1 personal edition or I am doing something wrong.
I once put a splash image which appears fine in beginning but now I have removed it, even deleted it from project/asset folder. Now when creating new build for iPhone/xcode, I don't know how but unity brings the same old splash image every time. I have tried changing the image. but it still shows old one. Even in xcode I can surely see the new image everywhere but on device, its always old one.
I have tried cleaning xcode project and deleting app from device.

Comment: Try clean your your project in `Xcode` then build again. :D

Comment: I have done it bro.. Likha to hai upper :D ^^

Comment: **Clean**. Product -> Clean Project. Bawlay...

Comment: Yes bro I know what that mean, and I have done it..

Comment: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/unity-5-3-1-i-have-deleted-a-splash-image-but-it-still-exist-somewhere-and-appears-in-beginning.377699/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but we ran into the same problem just recently.
he fix for this issue is to uninstall your project from the device and restart it.
This causes the device to delete the cached launch screens (yes, iOS caches all launch screens). When you install deploy your app now, it should use the new splash screen.